# `EvmError: NotActivated` when modifying variables in fallback

Tags: openzeppelin, fallback-function, reentrant-attacks

I get the strange `EvmError: NotActivated` when I put the `nonReentrant` modifier, like the [OZ](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol) one, on the fallback function. I need it there because I am working with [Diamond Proxies](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2535) which redirect all the logic to the fallback.

I tried messing around a little, and I spotted that this error comes when the modifier sets the `status` flag to `ENTERED` before the function begins, i.e. [here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol#L61). When I removed this line, the fallback worked just fine, but it's not reentrancy protected via the guard.

Any thoughts or ideas why this happens?

Edit: I recognized that this happens more generally when modifying any variable in the fallback function. I added a simple counter to my contract and the execution fails on `counter++`.